# ¿Cómo recorrer una lista con cadenas y eliminar las que tengan números?

Tags: python

Tengo un archivo de subtitulos que agregue el contenido en una lista, a la misma le elimine los repetidos y los /n del salto del linea. La cuestion es que no puedo terminar de eliminar las cadenas que contienen numeros. probe algo masomenos asi , pero no me funciono. Desde ya muchas gracias por la ayuda!!(aclaro x las dudas que vi que existe una funcion (Isdigit) algo asi creo que era pero no me dejan usarla :c

```py
lista=["hola","1234","chau"]
numeros=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
for i in lista:
    for character in i:
        if character in numeros:
            lista.pop(i)
print(lista)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vas por el buen camino. Tú código solo tiene unos detalles a corregir:

1. El resultado de iterar sobre una cadena es otra cadena y no un numérico. Cuando haces esto: `if character in numeros:` estas comparando una cadena con los valores de una lista de números, lo cual es inválido. Puedes trabajar con una lista de cadenas: 
   `numeros=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]`, o bien usar la función `character.isdigit()` que te retorna `True` si la cadena efectivamente es un número.
2. `pop()` efectivamente extrae (y borra) un elemento de la lista, el tema es que lo que espera esta función es un índice posicional (el número del elemento), no el elemento en sí, que es lo que estarías haciendo con `lista.pop(i)`, podrías aprovechar la función `enumerate()` que además de retornarte cada elemento de la lista, te da el índice de estos.
3. Por último, relacionado con el punto anterior, deberías eliminar el elemento ni bien encuentras la primer ocurrencia de un número en cada cadena y luego detener el ciclo, tal como lo tienes, el `for` continua haciendo un `pop()` múltiples veces.

Con estas observaciones tú código podría quedar así:

```
lista = ["hola","1234","chau"]
numeros = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]
for i, palabra in enumerate(lista):
    for character in palabra:
        if character in numeros:
            lista.pop(i)
            break

print(lista)
```

Por otro lado, solo a titulo informativo, en python puedes hacer uso de una técnica llamad "comprensión de listas", que permite transformar cualquier iterable de una forma muy expresiva y compacta, por ejemplo, esta solución podría ser reescrita así:

```
lista = [palabra for palabra in lista if not any(char.isdigit() for char in palabra)]
print(lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

La implementacion de pop no me parece conveniente segun lo que se, solo retorna un elemento de una lista. Y a no ser que vayas haciendo un append con en otra lista no veo como hacerlo de dicha forma.

Una alternativa seria replace que, toma un valor que no deseas de una lista y lo reemplaza con otro que desees, por lo cual al final te si toda una lista solo tiene numeros con esta implementacion te quedaria una string vacia.

Haciendolo con replace quedaria asi:

```py
lista=["hola","1234","chau"]

longitudLista=len(lista)
for i in range(longitudLista):
    for j in range(0,9):
        lista[i]=lista[i].replace(str(j),"")

print(lista)
```